# search multiple files for a string on AIX

Tags: grep, aix

I was trying to search multiple files for a string like this. Using AIX if this matters.

```
grep -r "gap" /u/user/.History/
/u/user/.History/server/user:
/u/user/.History/server/user:
```

This mostly worked except when files have strange characters listing the file name but not showing the match. So I added the string command like this. None of these methods worked. None of these commands give any output at all. It is acting like there are no matches even though I know there are.

```
strings /u/user/.History | grep gap
strings /u/user/.History/* | grep gap
cat /u/user/* | strings | grep gap
cat /u/user/.History/* | strings | grep gap
cat /u/user/.History/ | strings | grep gap
```

When I grepped on a single file with strings it gave this output. It just will not work when I do it on multiple files.

```
>strings /u/user/.History/server/user | grep gap
cd gap #▒#1612466141#▒#
gzip -cd gap2021-01-28.log.gz #▒#1612466384#▒#
```

Comment: What's your desired output? The list of matching filenames?

Comment: @JeffSchaller any match of the string `gap`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller added more output information.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively). Could be that AIX uses a different version of `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your `grep -r "gap" /u/user/.History/` command was actually finding the right files and displaying the matching lines; it's just that those lines also have non-printable portions that are obscuring the text when the line is written to your terminal.

My recommendation would be to filter the output so that it expands the non-printable portions into printable characters so that you can see the underlying text.

```
grep -r "gap" /u/user/.History/ | cat -v
```

or

```
find /u/user/.History/ -type f -exec grep gap {} + | cat -v
```

Would do the job. The [`cat -v`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-cat-command) command "displays nonprinting characters as visible characters..."

I created some test files to demonstrate the difference:

```
$ grep -r gap .
./user1/.History/server/user:
./user2/user:gap
```

compared to:

```
$ grep -r gap . | cat -v
./user1/.History/server/user:gap^?^?^?
./user2/user:gap
```

Where the ^?^?^? characters represent three "delete" characters. When printed as-is, those delete characters hide the three-character "gap" string.

Another option would be to pipe the output through [`od`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=o-od-command), perhaps `... | od -c`.

Comment: Are you using AIX? It doesn't seem to working. I am using an ancient version of AIX. 

`grep -r "gap" /u/user/.History/ | cat -v
/u/user/.History/server/user:
/u/user/.History/server/user:

find /u/user/.History/ -type f -exec grep gap {} + | cat -v
/u/user/.History/server/user:
/u/user/.History/server/user:`

Comment: I did test this on an AIX system, yes. I had to "fake" some non-printable characters to try and reproduce your situation, so maybe we have different data.  Could you post a sanitized (and perhaps uuencoded?) sample file for us to test against?

Comment: How would I post a sanitized file? I thought I did it above with this data: 

`>strings /u/user/.History/server/user | grep gap
cd gap #▒#1612466141#▒#
gzip -cd gap2021-01-28.log.gz #▒#1612466384#▒#`

Comment: I mean review a sample matching file for any private data, then pipe it to some kind of 7-bit-safe encoding like `uuencode` or `od`. The `#▒#1612466141#▒#` characters are a translation of the actual 8-bit character that's actually there.

Comment: So `od filename`? Don't ever use `od`.

Comment: My first idea is something like `uuencode filename filename`, where filename is your actual filename and yes it's listed twice. That should be safe to paste into your question as sample data (that people would have to uudecode, obviously). Change to the parent directory so that the uuencoded filename is just a base filename, to make it easier for people on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of ways to do this.

```
strings /u/user/.History/*/* | grep gap
```

With `find`.

```
find /u/user -xdev -type f -exec strings {} + | grep gap
find /u/user -xdev -type f -exec strings {} \; | grep gap
```